# Angular $http get parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm trying to figure out how to include query parameters in an Angular $http get call to a service to retrieve search suggestions AND then search, search is not working - I can get suggestions. I'm using AngularJS UI Bootstrap Typeahead for suggestions and then calling `search()` on selection with an ng-submit.

I have this for my route (state - UI Router) so that I can display the query parameter in the url on the results page
.state('search', {

```
url: '/search?query',
```

I init query as so

```
vm.searchTerms = $stateParams.query || '';
```

Then my $http get call in my getSuggestion function in the controller to retrieve the suggestions from the service

```
vm.getSuggestions = function(query) {
      return coreService.getSuggestions(query, {
        params: {query: query}
      })
      .then(function(es_return){
        var suggestions = es_return.hits.hits;
        return vm.autocomplete.suggestions = suggestions.map(function(item) {
          return item._source.suggestions;
          });
        });
      };
```

This setup doesn't work. So I looked at the docs and tried to include a config {} in there where config would be something like

```
var config = {
query: vm.searchTerms
}
```

and then

```
vm.getSuggestions = function(query) {
      return coreService.getSuggestions(query, config)
      .then(function(es_return){
        var suggestions = es_return.hits.hits;
        return vm.autocomplete.suggestions = suggestions.map(function(item) {
          return item._source.suggestions;
          });
        });
      };
```

and that still didn't work. So I'm not quite sure how to include the config {} with the query parameter to get the suggestions **AND** search to work. I'm not sure if it makes a difference but my ng-model on the form is vm.searchTerms for search()... should I just switch everything to query?

I have this in my `search()` in my controller

```
$state.go('search', {query: vm.searchTerms});
```

Comment: getSuggestions(query, {params: {query: query}}) << too much of query here...

Comment: @PetrAveryanov - I think I just figured this out, the params shouldn't be in the getSuggestion function - it should be in my search function. There's no reason to have it in my getSuggestions function - would you agree?